# Plones Portal_Setup -> Import steps doesn't work correctly

Tags: plone

I have a problem with Plone 4.0.1.
At portal_setup, when I want to import steps for a selected profile, these steps won't get selected. So for example when I want to run the steps to uninstall a product, the steps do not get selected. So I cannot use any of the profiles for installing/upgrading/uninstalling.

Is there any way to get this fixed again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What do you mean by "won't get selected"? Perhaps with screenshots, I think we may have a mismatch in vocabulary here.

Comment: At portal_setup->import, I see 71 steps. When I select any profile or snapshot, I still see all 71 steps. For example when I choose the profile as stated [here](http://projects.quintagroup.com/products/wiki/quintagroup.plonecaptchas#JoinForm), I still see all the steps and no changes. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: You mean that you select your profile and then you expect portal_setup to automatically mark the checkbox in front of only those import steps that this profile uses, or perhaps to only show those few steps instead of all 71?  It does not work like that.  portal_setup will always show all steps.  When importing a proile all 71 steps will be applied. It is up to the individual step import handlers to determine if they will do anything or not.  The 'skins' import handler will check for a skins.xml and stop if that file is not there.  There is no way to filter the steps without running them.

Comment: Note that the link you point to shows a screen shot of only two import steps, but this is simply because the screen shot then ends, cutting of the remaining import steps.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like the profiles I want to run are faulty. After I deactivated a product via quickinstaller and ran the uninstall profile, I remove it from the buildout. But after a new buildout, the profiles for this product are still existent and marked red. When I try to remove these steps with portal_setup->manage, I get an error 404 after I tried to delete them. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Right, so to clarify the question: after removing a product you still see product-specific GenericSetup steps listed in portal_setup (in red), and you want to know how to remove these.

Comment: Yes, also removing them via portal_setup->manage (which I think is exactly for that) does not work but just leads to a 404 after I selected the steps and clicked to remove them.

Comment: Can you edit the original question so it fits the new question? Also, I don't remember any Delete buttons for import steps. You have Plone 4.0.1 which should show those steps with a red/orange warning colour but it will otherwise ignore them without any bad effects. For cleanup you could write some custom code like remove_old_import_step here: http://dev.plone.org/plone/browser/Products.LinguaPlone/branches/3.x/Products/LinguaPlone/migrations.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating Plone to 4.0.9 with some additional upgrade steps to clean up Plone helped resolving this problem, thanks for the help :)